# Flutter Java Error when runing command for Android license status unknown

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, environment-variables

I am facing some errors while setting up flutter on my Windows machine.

After running the  `flutter doctor` flutter doctor command I got an error asking me to accept the license. [Android license status unknown.]

After running the command to update license, i.e   `flutter doctor --android-licenses`  I get below errors

```
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
PS C:\Users\Osas Divine> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class Divine\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\..
```

I have installed Android SDK tools (obselete) and Android command-line tools

I have also set the JAVA_HOME and /bin on my environment variables

Comment: Which JAVA version do you use? I am getting this error since I switched from Oracle JDK 8 to OpenJDK 13. So maybe it is a problem with the underlying JAVA version?

Comment: I am using java 8

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is: having a space in your android skd path: PS C:\Users\Osas Divine

You should install Android sdk in another folder or rename user profile